# Debug the script

Tags: ruby

I need guidance to resolve a error while running a Ruby script, there is a module which is producing an error. The error error message is below:

> ./7toEIS_v2.rb:304:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

The erroring function is below:

```
300 def showContOwner(cont_name)
301     File.open($physcontinfo).each_line { |i|
302         i.chomp!
303         cont,blah,model,ontap,loc,owner = i.split(",")
304         ($phys[cont] ||=[] << model + "," + ontap + "," + loc + "," + owner)
305     }
306     return cont_name + " - to be executed by " + $phys[cont_name][0].split(",")[3]
307 end
```

I have checked by changing the code that it reads the file though.

Also this code was written for earlier version of Ruby, and currently I am using the version below:

> ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin15

Comment: One of the variables `model`, `ontap`, `loc` or `owner` is `nil`. Have you checked what the value of `i` is when it crashes?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , and also explain your understanding of what the error means.

Comment: With the information provided I can't diagnose your problem, but as an aside you could write `cont,_,s = "a,b,c,d,e,f".split(',',3) #=> ["a", "b", "c,d,e,f"]`, in which case `cont #=>"a"` and `s #=> "c,d,e,f"`, allowing you to write  `($phys[cont] ||=[]) << s`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still open I'd maybe look into https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug or https://github.com/pry/pry. Or for that matter any other debugging tool that would allow you to check the code step by step ^^
Without more context, it is impossible for us to pinpoint the exact issue.